# How to search for articles containing two words?

Tags: search, order

I'd like to serach my blog for articles that contain the two words `bash` and `variable`. There is an article that contains both words, but it is not found. It seems to me that the wordpress search only searches for a single string. If I search e.g. for `bash script`, it finds articles. If I search for `script bash` it doesn't find one, since the words have a different order in the article.

Is it somehow possible to allow the search for multiple words irrespectively of their order?

Answer (score 0):

Ex.

```
http://www.site.com/?s=as+sa
```

This gives a perfect search result irrespective of the order of words.

If you want to add a custom query then you can use following:

`$query = new WP_Query( 's=keyword+keyword2' );`

and iterate through your query result.

Try this out.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing does not seem to be native search behavior. The SQL query WordPress is producing for such search request is something like:

```
SELECT wp_posts.id
FROM   wp_posts
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND ( ( ( wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%bash%' )
                OR ( wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%bash%' ) )
             AND ( ( wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%script%' )
                    OR ( wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%script%' ) ) )
       AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
       AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' )
ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT  0, 5
```

It only checks for presence of both words, their order in title/content is not checked for at all.

It is likely something (plugin/theme) is modifying search behavior in your environment.